# DynamoDB query subsegments show some of them take way too long - How to debug

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I tried using https://github.com/shelfio/dynamodb-query-optimized to speed up the dynamodb response time when querying time-series data. Nothing fancy, uses a GSI for the query (id and timestamp) and uses them in the key expression. Not much to filter out in the filter expression so the index is optimized.

For some reason, if I use the queryOptimized method (that queries 2-way i.e scan forward and backward), some of the dynamodb query subsegments start taking way too long. In the range of 16seconds-25seconds which is killing the performance and resulting in API gateway timeouts.

The first 20-25 subsegments seem to start at approximately the same time and have decent performance i.e under 500ms, However, after 20-25 subsegments, It starts about 300ms later and the duration of most of these subsegments is really long.

How do I debug what is going on here? Doesn't seem to give any further info in traces. Retries are 0 for all of those subsegments, No failures or errors either. The table is configured to have on-demand capacity so do not imagine capacity to be the issue. Lambda function also has the max (10GB memory allocated) to it. Any ideas on how to figure out what's going on?

Comment: You don't mention how it performs when you're doing a regular query. I assume normally? I see you filed an issue with the library. Probably you should dig into their code for some odd state management bug.

Comment: @hunterhacker Takes relatively less time with query regular. I was hoping to get better response time with query optimized but don't see it, infact takes longer

Comment: So it’s a bug in the library. Either hope the maintainer fixes it, go spelunking into the library code to fix it yourself, write your own version of the library, or abandon it. You also could just shard the PK into ten PKs and 10x speed up a standard multi-threaded query speed.